# GA4: is it possible to add custom parameters to automatic events like view_search_result?

Tags: google-analytics-4

I've noticed that automatically generated events like first_visit, session_start, view_search_result do not contain the custom parameters I set in the config options for all the other events generated on the page. Is there any way to add parameters to those events?

Answer (score 1):

No - you'll have to duplicate the event and add your own custom parameters.

Comment: Do you know how to duplicate the session_start event?